# ¿Cómo ordenar una lista según el orden de otra lista de objetos dinámicos en python?

Tags: python, json, arraylist, objeto

Quiero buscar en una lista de objeto un id específico, en este caso el **id** 3 y agregarlo en otra lista:

**Tengo estas lista:**

```
list1=['"kjnkjnk1"','qweqwe2','asdasasd3']


list2=[{"id":"asdasasd3","nombre":"steven"},{"id":"kjnkjnk1","nombre":"jose"},{"id":"qweqwe2","nombre":"ramon"}]
```

**Resultado final :**
  una lista arreglada

```
newlist=[{
{"id":"kjnkjnk1","nombre":"jose"},
{"id":"qweqwe2","nombre":"ramon"},
{"id":"asdasasd3","nombre":"steven"},
}]
```

Comment: Necesito una forma mas optima que hacerlo con un ciclo for quiero sacar directamente algo asi como list.id

Comment: que intentastes, alli solo tienes la lista y el resultado, queremos ver un ejemplo minimo verificable

Comment: Si tienes todos los diccionarios en una lista no te quedará más remedio que iterar por la lista y comparar cada campo "id" de cada diccionario con el id buscado. Si quieres una solución más óptima debes cambiar la estructura de datos. Por ejemplo, todos ellos podrían estar en un solo diccionario cuyas claves fueran los ids y los valores los datos. Por ejemplo `data={3: {"nombre":"steven", "age":23}, 1:{"nombre": "jose"}... etc}`. En este caso puedes acceder directamente a steven con `data[3]` (3 sería su id)

Comment: y como iterar ?

Comment: esto es lo que quiero lograr lo actualice

Comment: estoy usando getstream y me manda los objetos al asar  asi pero me los desordena y necesito ordenarlos para mostrarlos

Comment: Entonces lo que quieres es ordenar la lista de diccionarios por la key nombre? ¿que versión de Python usas?

Comment: por la key id  utilizo la version 3.6

Comment: A vale, ordenarlos según el orden de lista1 ¿verdad?  Deberías editar la pregunta y cambiar el título explicando esto que comentas en ella, ya que es confusa tal como está.

Comment: ok vale ya lo arreglo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Realmente no es un problema de ordenamiento, no queremos ordenar `lista2`, sino que se trata de reorganizarla de acuerdo a `lista1` que nos da el orden ya hecho.

Si **asumimos que toda `id` de `list2` está en `lista1`**, podemos usar `list.sort` de la siguiente manera:

```
list1 = ['kjnkjnk1', 'qweqwe2', 'asdasasd3']


list2 = [{"id": "asdasasd3", "nombre": "steven"},
         {"id":"kjnkjnk1", "nombre":"jose"},
         {"id":"qweqwe2","nombre":"ramon"}
         ] 

list2.sort(key=lambda d: list1.index(d["id"]))
```

básicamente le decimos que por cada diccionario de `list2` obtenga el valor de la clave `id` y que busque el índice de esta en `list1`, ordenando de acuerdo a dicho índice.

El problema es que esto es muy ineficiente en tiempo de ejecución si tu lista es muy grande por culpa de `list.index` (por cada llamada debe iterar sobre la lista para buscar el elemento y obtener su índice).

Si lo anterior es un problema, podemos sacrificar algo de RAM para generar un diccionario a partir de la primera lista de la forma: `{key1: indice_key1, key2: indice_key2, ...}`. Hecho esto el problema se reduce a la búsqueda de una clave en una tabla hash, muchísimo más eficiente que buscar un item en una lista:

```
sort_keys = {key: idx for idx, key in enumerate(list1)}
list2.sort(key = lambda d: sort_keys[d["id"]])
```

> ```
> >>> list2
> [{'id': 'kjnkjnk1', 'nombre': 'jose'},
>  {'id': 'qweqwe2', 'nombre': 'ramon'},
>  {'id': 'asdasasd3', 'nombre': 'steven'}]
> ```

Si no podemos asumir que toda id de lista2 esté en lista1, podemos hacer uso de `dict.get` para dejar los diccionarios sin id en `list1` al final de la lista con el mismo orden original:

```
import math


list1 = ['qweqwe2', 'asdasasd3']

list2 = [{"id": "asdasasd3", "nombre": "steven"},
         {"id":"kjnjknk1", "nombre":"jose"},
         {"id":"qweqwe2","nombre":"ramon"}, 
         {"id":"qdadgga","nombre":"luis"}
         ]

sort_keys = {key: idx for idx, key in enumerate(list1)}
list2.sort(key = lambda d: sort_keys.get(d["id"], math.inf))
```

> ```
> >>> list2
> [{'id': 'qweqwe2', 'nombre': 'ramon'},
>  {'id': 'asdasasd3', 'nombre': 'steven'},
>  {'id': 'kjnjknk1', 'nombre': 'jose'},
>  {'id': 'qdadgga', 'nombre': 'luis'}]
> ```

Comment: El mago lo hizo otra vez..